# Adding Markers in Maps during app is running unsuccessful

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, marker

I have been trying to implement markers in my google maps activity while the application runs. There are some pre-defined "Location" objects, and there is a marker at the "current location" of the user.

Using a `SeekBar`, I'm trying to change the `range` of the current location in which the markers of the location objects should be displayed, but on changing the `SeekBar`, nothing happens (no markers get added, there's just one at the current location). Apologies for the unwanted extra code, I believe the most important parts to look at are `onConnected()`, `onSeekBarChangedListener()` and `onMapReady()`

This is my MapsActivity.java:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.
OnConnectionFailedListener, OnSeekBarChangeListener {

    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
    private SeekBar rangeSeekBar;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private Intent intent;
    private Location currentLocation;
    private Location[] locations;
    private double range;

    Location locationOne;
    Location locationTwo;
    Location locationThree;
    Location locationFour;
    Location locationFive;
    Location locationSix;
    Location locationSeven;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        locationOne = new Location("");
        locationTwo = new Location("");
        locationThree = new Location("");
        locationFour = new Location("");
        locationFive = new Location("");
        locationSix = new Location("");
        locationSeven = new Location("");

        locationOne.setLatitude(10.1399);
        locationOne.setLongitude(76.1784);

        locationTwo.setLatitude(10.2244);
        locationTwo.setLongitude(76.1978);

        locationThree.setLatitude(9.6175);
        locationThree.setLongitude(76.4301);

        locationFour.setLatitude(9.5987);
        locationFour.setLongitude(76.3116);

        locationFive.setLatitude(9.6175);
        locationFive.setLongitude(76.4301);

        locationSix.setLatitude(9.6737);
        locationSix.setLongitude(76.5610);

        locationSeven.setLatitude(15.5152);
        locationSeven.setLongitude(73.8565);

        locations = new Location[]{
            locationOne,
            locationTwo,
            locationThree,
            locationFour,
            locationFive,
            locationSix,
            locationSeven
        };

        rangeSeekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.rangeSeekBar);
        rangeSeekBar.setProgress(0);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        googleApiClient.disconnect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        LatLng india = new LatLng(20.5937, 78.9629);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(india, 5));

        if(googleApiClient==null){
            googleApiClient  = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        }

        googleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MapsActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MapsActivity.this,new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},1);
        } else {
            currentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);

            LatLng currentLoc = new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(),currentLocation.getLongitude());
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(currentLoc).title("Your current location"));
        }

        addingMarkersInRange(0);
    }

    public void addingMarkersInRange(double range){
        for(int i=0;i<locations.length;i++){
            if(currentLocation.distanceTo(locations[i])<range) {
                LatLng tempLatLng = new LatLng(locations[i].getLatitude(), locations[i].getLongitude());
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(tempLatLng));
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(tempLatLng));
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        addingMarkersInRange(rangeSeekBar.getProgress()*700000);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it really showing error ? Or markers are not showing ?

Comment: @Kirankumar Zinzuvadia yes I'm sorry, I meant markers are not showing. There's no error.

Answer (score 0):

Your `addinMarkersInRange()` method is only adding markers for `LatLng`s in `locations` array. So, you need to add to `locations` array before invoking `addingMarkersInRange`. But, since you cannot add to an array, please change locations to a `List` and you should be good to go.

You are not setting listener on `SeekBar` object. Please set `OnSeekBarChangeListener` like so in your onCreate():

```
// code you already have
rangeSeekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.rangeSeekBar);
rangeSeekBar.setProgress(0);

// register event listener here
rangeSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
```

Comment: But the locations array isn't empty! I don't quite get you...When I run the application, there's only 1 marker(at the current location), and nothing else. Not even the markers in the array are showing up when I change the seekbar..

Comment: @Ryuzaki Sounds silly, but did you try zooming in, because you locations array has LatLng's pretty close to each other.

Comment: Okay, so next thing is you are calculating distance using distanceTo(). distanceTo() returns distance in meters. How are you ensuring that range is in meters?

Comment: Umm, I'm confused, why does that matter? toDistance() returns a double in Meyers and I'm using a seekbar with range 0-7000000, so...It will just compare the distance with whatever value on the seekbar is made..

Comment: @Ryuzaki You missed setting OnSeekBarChangeListener on your SeekBar. Please check my edit to answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have issue in addingMarkersInRange().
But let proceed in a way, 
First set listener to seekbar. Then set max value of seekbar.
Now initially call addingMarkersInRange(1) instead of passing zero.

Now while seek bar change make use of isfromUser flag in onProgress change.

And remove that onCameraChange() & place it outside of for loop. And use latlongbound to animate camera zoom level.

Now run and check any change made on UI ...!